# Remove window count from tmux session menu

Tags: tmux

When I'm switching between sessions in tmux I see a menu that also shows the number of windows opened in every session.

Please note, this is not about window numbering but window count. See image:

[image]

I'd rather not see the `N windows` part, I don't wanna see that `gopass` session has 1 window.

It's irrelevant information for me, is it possible to get rid of this? I want just a list of session names.

Comment: Do you just dislike the counts, or are they in the way of some script you are writing?

Comment: I'm not going to write any script. I'm just not interested in numbers of windows on every session

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/2h3lin/how_can_i_remove_the_window_number_from_the_tmux/

Comment: @InonPeled, no, it's not related, there is window name, my question is about session names

Answer (score 0):

These are the keys to press to choose each item and you can't remove them.

Comment: The keys to press are `0`, `1`, etc to choose the session. My question is how to remove information about window numbering

Comment: Oh right, you want to remove the "1 windows" etc. You need to use choose-tree -F.

Comment: If you run 2.9-rc or master you can use tmux display -pF '#{tree_mode_format}' to see the default format, otherwise you will need to look at the code.